# Map foreign key in Fluent NHibernate without object property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

My question is, is there a possible Fluent NHibernate mapping for Parent and Child objects that does not require the Child object to have a Parent object property? I haven't figured out how to map the reference back to the Parent. When I call Create with the mappings as-is, I get an exception because the Child object does not have the required foreign key (required in the data store) back to the Parent.

I have two POCO classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

And some mappings:

```
public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
        this.Table("Parents");
        this.Id(x => x.Id);
        this.Map(x => x.Name);
        this.HasMany(x => x.Childs).KeyColumn("ChildId").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

public class ChildMap : ClassMap<Child>
{
    public ChildMap()
    {
        this.Table("Childs");
        this.Id(x => x.Id);
        this.Map(x => x.Name);
        // Needs some sort of mapping back to the Parent for "Child.ParentId"
    }
}
```

And Create method:

```
public Parent Create(Parent t)
{
    using (this.session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        this.session.Save(t);
        this.session.Transaction.Commit();
    }
    return t;
}
```

I want to be able to create a Parent object that has a list of Child objects, but not have the Child objects have references back to their Parent (other than the Parent ID). I want to do this to avoid the circular reference from Parent to a list of Childs back to the Parent object, since that is causing issues with JSON serialization.

Comment: Is mapping the parent property (in `Child`) to a private field an option?

Comment: That's what I'm doing, though I'm trying to avoid it since I can't then run queries on the `ParentId` property.  It seems like I should be able to map a property with a foreign key constraint to a column without requiring an object...

Comment: In the case of the original question, Felipe's answer is correct. Don't serialize the entities directly, transform them into a DTO or ViewModel  first, getting the exact structure you want first.

Answer (score 3):

You can map these entities without problem, try this:

```
public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
        this.Table("Parents");
        this.Id(x => x.Id);
        this.Map(x => x.Name);
        this.HasMany(x => x.Childs).KeyColumn("ChildId").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

public class ChildMap : ClassMap<Child>
{
    public ChildMap()
    {
        this.Table("Childs");
        this.Id(x => x.Id);
        this.Map(x => x.Name);
        this.Map(x => x.ParentId);
        // if you have a reference of Parent object, you could map as a reference, for sample:
        this.References(x => x.Parent).Column("ParentId");
    }
}
```

When you get entities from ISession, do not serialize it to some format because these can be proxies of nhibernate instead entities objects. Try to create [DTO (Data Transfer Object) classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and convert these entities to a DTO object, and serialize it. You will avoid circular references. For sample:

```
public class ParentDTO
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    /* here you just have the primitive types or other DTOs, 
       do not reference any Entity type*/
}
```

And when you need to read the values to share the serialized value:

```
var dto = ISession.Query<Parent>()
                  .Select(x => 
                      new ParentDTO() { 
                           Id = x.Id, 
                           Name = x.Name, 
                           ParentId = x.ParentId)
                  .ToList();
```

Get this result from the Data Access Layer and try to serialize, for sample:

```
var result = Serialize(dto);
```

Comment: A critical piece for me that your answer does not address is the `ParentId` property must have a foreign key constraint on the `Id` property of the `Parent` object.  You just `Map`ped it, so it has no constraints on it at all.

Comment: I aggree with you @PatrickQuirk, but in the model that OP provided does not has a reference, just an `Id`.